# Laravel - validation localization doesn't work

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

Whenever I use the `trans()` function to return a specific translation from the `validation.php` file, it works just perfectly. I have two languages in my application and the translations get returned for both of them.

However, whenever I use the Laravel validator, it returns messages in the default locale only. Is there something I need to specify in the validator? How do I make it work for both languages?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass as 3rd parameters your translations. Let's assume you have defined your fields, rules and validator like in the following code:

```
$data = Input::only('title');
$rules['title'] = 'required|min:20|max:80',
$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules,
            Lang::get('forms.validation.entry'));
```

Now you need to define your translations. Let's assume you need translation for `fr` lang so you need co create `lang/fr/forms.php` file and put the following content into it:

```
<?php

return

array (
  'validation' => array (
     'entry' => array (
         'title.required' => 'Your translation for title required',
         'title.min' => 'Your translation for title min',
         'title.max' => 'Your translation for title max',
      )
  )
);
```

Of course you can create file with simpler array but it's just example - instead of `forms.validation.entry` it could be for example just `forms` or `validation`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem originated from my localization implementation. I've added `App::setLocale(Session::get('lang'));` to the `App::before()` method in the `filters.php` file and it all works now.

Answer (score 0):

in resources/lang/en folder laravel have validation.php. When you create new language so you can copy this file to new created language folder and then edit it to this language.

for example you wanna create fr language

.

```
/resources/lang/fr/validation.php and translate it to this language
```